# SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI setting in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, spring-cloud-config, kubernetes-networking

I have a simple setup of 2 containers, one for configuration and one for gateway.

Below is the definitions of service and deployments. They get created fine but the gateway container isn't able to connect to the `http://configuration:8888` and throws unknown host error.

The configuration server is running Nginx on port `8888`.

I am able to access the configuration from a browser with URL `http://configuration/actuator/`.

I thought the pods in Kubernetes should be able to communicate fine as long as they are in the same network (host here). Not sure what is missing here.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: configuration
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 8888
      targetPort: 8888
    selector:
      app: configuration
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
```

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: configuration
    name: configuration
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: configuration
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: configuration
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: JVM_OPTS
            value: -Xss512k -XX:MaxRAM=128m
          image: <image>
          name: configuration
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data
            name: configuration-claim0
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: configuration-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: configuration-claim0
  status: {}
```

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: gateway
    name: gateway
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: gateway
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: gateway
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: JVM_OPTS
            value: -Xss512k -XX:MaxRAM=128m
          **- name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI
            value: http://configuration:8888**
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
            value: container
          image: <image>
          name: gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using:
`hostNetwork: true`

So you can reference the service using: `http://localhost:8888`.

Otherwise, remove `hostNetwork: true`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before and it didn't work. now it seems to work. I added hostNetwork as a backup option. if i remove it, is it possible to connect to the config?

Comment: yes, I think so